# How to find newest file in a given directory and use it in diff call

Tags: bash, shell, linux-kernel

I'm trying to call diff on two files in a bash script, one being given using a variable, and the other being the newest file in a directory.  Here's the command I'm using, where $FILE is a variable that points to the file in the current directory, and $DIR is a variable that points to another directory where I'm searching for the newest file:

```
diff $FILE $DIR/$(ls -tr | tail -n 1) > diff.txt
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in trying to call the "search for newest file" command in the directory $DIR.  Does this not return the newest file in the directory given by $DIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written it the `ls` command is run in the current directory. You can fix this simply by explicitly telling `ls` which directory to list:

```
diff "$FILE" "$DIR/$(ls -tr $DIR | tail -n 1)" > diff.txt
```

The `diff` command has a return code of `0` if no difference is found and a return code of `1` if a difference is found. The return code of the previous command is stored in the variable `$?` and can be used in a following `if` statement:

```
if (( $? == 0 ))
then
    echo "match..."
else
    echo "no match..."
fi
```

Be careful when doing this as `$?` is overwritten by any subsequent commands. This can even include commands within the same pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
diff $FILE $DIR/$(ls -tr $DIR| tail -n 1) > diff.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run `ls` on `$DIR` only:

```
diff "$FILE" "$DIR/$(ls -tr "$DIR"| tail -n 1)" > diff.txt
```

Also note extra quoting in command is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that this was the only thing that worked right:

```
diff "$FILE" "$DIR/$(ls -tr "$DIR"| tail -n 1)" > diff.txt
```

Thanks guys, your input helped a lot.

One more quick question. Is there a way to tell if diff found that the two files were different?  Could I add the entire line of code above into an "if" statement somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

if !  DIFFSTATEMENT ; then
  echo "they are different"
fi